# RMAN full backup until specific SCN

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2, rman

Is it possible to do a full database backup with until specific SCN using RMAN?

For example, I know there are SCNs numbered 10002, 10003, 10004, 10005, and so forth. Can I take a database backup until SCN 10004 using RMAN?

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNTIL SCN` parameter, for example:

```
RMAN> BACKUP AS BACKUPSET DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG UNTIL SCN 10002
```

[Relevant Oracle Docs page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96565/rcmsynta57.htm)

Comment: Hello I face error, RMAN>  BACKUP AS BACKUPSET DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG SCN 1487655;

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00558: error encountered while parsing input commands
RMAN-01009: syntax error: found "scn": expecting one of: "auxiliary, channel, delete, diskratio, filesperset, force, format,

Comment: Wellp, you forgot `UNTIL` between `ARCHIVELOG` and `SCN`

Comment: Still face issue :
RMAN> BACKUP AS BACKUPSET DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG UNTIL SCN 10002;

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00558: error encountered while parsing input commands
RMAN-01009: syntax error: found "until": expecting one of: "auxiliary, channel, delete, diskratio, filesperset, force, format, from, include, keep, maxsetsize, noexclude, nokeep, not, pool, reu